# Qué estructura de datos representa este código en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, estructuras-de-datos

```
webpackJsonp([25, 5], {
    1434: function(t, e, o) {
        o(56), o(294), o(753), t.exports = o(784)
    },
    155: function(t, e, o) {},

     ....

     n : function(n1,n2,n3) {} 

}, [1434]);
```

El contenido entre llaves no interesa. Busque las distintas formas de definir arrays, clases, funciones en javascript y no veo que coincida con ninguno

Comment: A simple vista eso parece una función que por *argumentos* tiene un `array`, un `object` y un `array` respectivamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un archivo bundle y mangled (variables de nombre mínimo) de webpack.

Lo que ves es un llamado a una función (webpackJsonp) que recibe como parámetros un array, un objeto y otro array. A simple vista es imposible saber qué hace con ellos, pero el funcionamiento de webpack en general es:

- Los parámetros son referencias a métodos/funciones de otro parámetro,
  o bien objetos planos en donde cada llave es una expresión de
  función, a la manera de métodos.
- Cada uno de esos "métodos" está representado por un número, como si
  fueran una línea y los llamaras haciendo un GOSUB (al estilo años
  80).
- Esos métodos a su vez esperan como parámetros funciones que luego se
  ejecutarán usando como parámetro uno de sus "métodos hermanos"

No es trivial explicar la estructura interna del bundle y mangle de webpack y definitivamente no se puede encapsular en una respuesta de S.O.